# Android: Slide menu isn't working when the content is Scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, slide

I'm trying to implement menu like facebook and bbm which the main content is vertically scrollable and it has sidebar if slide horizontally. 
What i get is the sidebar doesn't show up when i slide horizontally but the vertical scroll is doing fine. 
When i tried changing the scrollview to another layout like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout, the horizontal slide is working fine.
Has anyone ever encountered this?

Comment: How you implement Slide Menu? Do You extend `ViewGroup`? If true, do you override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method of `ViewGroup`?

Comment: i made custom linear layout on mainactivity and the scrollview is in a fragment. i didn't use viewgroup.